# XSLT not calling method belonging to Java parent class: ClassNotFoundException & NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, xslt, noclassdeffounderror, classnotfoundexception

I am trying to make a call to a method, let's say `getFullName()` within an XSL stylesheet. The method belongs to a class `Person`, which is a superclass of `Student`. I have defined the `Student` class in the XSL stylesheet namespace as follows: `xmlns:std="java:example.code.Student"`. However, during runtime, I get the following two errors: **ClassNotFoundException** and **NoClassDefFoundError** for `example.code.abstract.Person`. Seems like the class definitions for Person isn't available during runtime? Shouldn't the `Student` object have access to its parent's methods?

Comment: Are you using the Xalan Java extensions?

Comment: Yeah I am using those extensions I think

Answer (score 0):

> Seems like the class definitions for Person isn't available during runtime?

Yes, that would be the correct interpretation of the error.

> Shouldn't the Student object have access to its parent's methods?

Yes, the Student object will have *access* to the parent's non-private methods. That is, provided the parent's class is available at runtime. In other words, the child class does not embed the parent's methods, so it will need the parent class to be made available for access.

The parent class is unavailable during the load of the child class, resulting in the *NoClassDefFoundError*. You'll need to ensure that the both the parent and child classes are available at runtime to prevent the error from occuring.

Comment: How can I make sure those classes are available at runtime? I am using Maven to keep track of dependencies, and it does look like the `Person` jar is included in `Student`'s dependencies. I also have another package that reads info from Hibernate, and successfully makes calls from the `Student` class that are inherited from `Person`

Comment: Are you invoking `java org.apache.xalan.xslt.Process` from the command line? If so, you'll need to specify the CLASSPATH environment variable, or use the `-cp` or `-classpath` flags to the java executable.

Comment: I checked the stack trace and the code makes a call to `com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TemplatesImpl.newTransformer` and later, the `NoClassDefFoundError` is thrown after `java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0`. For the CLASSPATH, I did verify that the classpath is set to the directory where all the jars are kept and made available during runtime. I am using Spring dm Server by the way.

Comment: How are you invoking the XSL transformation? I'm afraid I haven't understood this part, for I've never worked with Spring dm Server.

Comment: I think the code invokes it by making a call to `javax.xml.transform.Transformer.transform`

Comment: Ah ok, I'm getting an idea of what you're doing. I'm not sure how you've organized your classes and bundles (especially the bundle manifest). It might be worth looking at what packages are imported into the bundle executing this code. It is simply not enough to have JARs in the same directory. I'm afraid that with my limited knowledge of OSGi, I can only advice to a limited amount.

Comment: I'm using Maven, and in the `pom.xml` I have noted the package to be imported via `<Import-Package>example.code.abstract</Import-Package>` and when the project is built, it is also in the `MANIFEST.MF`: `Import-Package: example.code.abstract` That should make the bundle available at runtime right?